# FQL to retrieve and paginate for all video posts on friends' wall

Tags: facebook, pagination, facebook-fql

I have been trying to fetch all video posts from my friends' wall (say 20 at a time)

Below query

SELECT created_time, post_id, actor_id, type, updated_time, attachment FROM stream WHERE created_time>1075593600 AND post_id in (select post_id from stream where ('video') in attachment AND source_id IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())  limit 100)

returns all videos on my friends wall in their first 100 posts

Using this query I will not know how many videos will be returned in the result.

Is there a way I can fetch first 20 video posts using FQL?